# VBA Search for the display name in Outlook global address by providing the office

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I would like to retrieve the display name from the Outlook global address by providing the office.
I know how to get the office when I know the display name (in VBA) but not the other way around.

Actually, I receive an Excel file with a list of offices (which are actually meeting rooms) and have to provide the corresponding display names. Similar to what we do manually in Outlook.
(Example in the image below to illustrate what I mean)

[image: Example in Outlook]

Answer (score 0):

In VBA you need to iterate over all items in the GAL and check their [CompanyName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.exchangeuser.companyname) property.

```
    Dim outlApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim outlNameSpace As Outlook.Namespace
    Dim outlGAL As Outlook.AddressList
    Dim outlEntry As Outlook.AddressEntries
    Dim outlMember As Outlook.AddressEntry

    Set outlApp = new Outlook.Application()
    Set outlNameSpace = outlApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set outlGAL = outlNameSpace.GetGlobalAddressList()
    
    hitCounter = 0
    
    'store address entries
    Set outlEntry = outlGAL.AddressEntries

    'loop through address entries and extract details
    For i = 1 To outlEntry.Count
        Set outlMember = outlEntry.Item(i)
        
        'check if address type is user type (not e.g distribution list)
        If outlMember.AddressEntryUserType = olExchangeUserAddressEntry Then
            
            hitCounter = hitCounter + 1
            
            MsgBox outlMember.GetExchangeUser.CompanyName
            
        End If
    Next i
```

Another possible solution is to use the [CreateRecipient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.namespace.createrecipient) method, but it will not help because it accepts the name of the recipient - it can be a string representing the display name, the alias, or the full SMTP email address of the recipient.

The Outlook object model doesn't provide any method for searching the GAL with properties like Office.

Comment: Isn't it a way to find it directly?  If you look to my code to get the alias, there is no loop

Comment: And are you able to search for a user passing the office name string?

Comment: No,  this is reason of my post.  I can receive a list of hundred of offices and I wanted to avoid to get the displayed name manually as I show to the screenshot.

Comment: Another possible solution is to use the [CreateRecipient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.namespace.createrecipient) method, but it will not help because it accepts the name of the recipient - it can be a string representing the display name, the alias, or the full SMTP email address of the recipient.

Comment: There is no other method for that unfortunately.